# Проблема при включении виджетов

Tags: php, wordpress, виджет

Существует сайт на WP. При включении виджетов весь блок с контентом сжимается, лишь картинки остаются без изменений. Я пробовал самостоятельно зарегестрировать место для виджета, и вставить его в нужное место, но все-равно сайт сжимается...В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/themes/sugar-and-spice
Используется данная тема

Comment: Я ничего не понял, но думаю что дело не в php или вротпресе, а в поломанных CSS структуре HTML.

Можешь дать ссылку на сайт с этой проблемой например?

Comment: Не, долго копался в файлах. При включении виджетов в админке, и отключении sidabar"а, все-равно регистрируется место для виджетов.

Comment: я бы вам посоветовал сделать бэкап, потом удалить тему и установить её заново